# This positively affects patient lives and

Tags: grammaticality, grammar

I am not sure whether patient needs to be plural or singular in the title sentence.
If it's plural is it then "patients' lives"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are referring to patients in general, you will be unlikely to upset anyone if you punctuate it as:

*This positively affects patients' lives.*

Comment: yes, that is right. I am talking about patients in general and how they are affected by different diseases/symptoms/etc. Thank you very much for your comment. I will go for patient's lives then :-)

Comment: NOOO! Patients' lives. Apostrophe after the 's'.

Comment: wuuh typo, but made it right in the text, though :-)

Answer (score 1):

1. "This positively affects patient lives and"
2. "This positively affects patients' lives and"

In the first sentence, the group "patient lives" is a compound noun. Here you should just pluralize the last noun of that group.

In the second sentence, the group "patients' lives" is a genitive construction. Here you should pluralize both nouns.

Both sentences are valid and their meaning is equal.